Using Anchor IDL Program for Raydium AMM
I'm trying to use the IDL, I found at: [Raydium-IO]https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-idl/blob/master/raydium_amm/idl.json
The problem is: I can't decode the data. It seem that the signature hash is not good.
  "version": "0.3.0",
  "name": "raydium_amm",
  "instructions": [
  ...

I think the "name" is not good. When I verify the signature hash:
Instruction: initialize2, Sighash: b'\xd9h,\xa1\xb8\x9b\xffy'

But My initialize2 data is:
b'\x01\xfe\x8f\xdb\xa0e\x00\x00'

To test here is a signature of a initialize2 transaction:
4v6Y5cfoD11YoUa6k1u9e9mupzFuRWA3b9Ko7cUumxwsE2kak8XNWmuRrBc22ouFTMY1WHrQnBKrYNHh5uT7iQfe
I'm pretty sure, this is the problem. Because I already use moonshot and pumpfun IDL, and they work fine.
Is anyone have another IDL for Raydium? Or the good name?
Thanks for your help.
